# How to use a redux form width "Field" with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have this component in my form :

```
  <Field className={styles.formcontrol}
    component='input'
    name={name}
    type={type}
  />
```

This is a field from redux-form.

However, I have to use the bootstrap for this form. And Bootstrap input looks like this :

```
<FormGroup controlId='login'>
    <FormControl name='email' placeholder='Login' />
</FormGroup>
```

How can I apply Bootstrap style (the FormGroup component) but still use a "Field" from redux-form ?

Comment: You can wrap bootstrap component with your custom component and use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a stateless function which will include your Bootstrap component.

```
// The props will be passed by redux-form.
const MyCustomComponent = ({input}: props) => (
    <FormGroup controlId='login'>
        <FormControl name='email' placeholder='Login' value={input.value} onChange={input.onChange} {...props}/>
    </FormGroup>
)
```

and use it with `Field` as

```
<Field 
    className={styles.formcontrol}
    component={MyCustomComponent}
    name={name}
    type={type}
/>
```

Here is the [nice article](https://medium.com/@mirkomariani/functional-components-with-react-stateless-functions-and-ramda-e83e54fcd86b) explaining stateless components in React.

Comment: Okay but it seems that according to the form, the inputs are empty. Should we pass the value in an onChange?

Comment: @Kazuwa Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into using a stateless function that returns your component.

http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/Field.md/#usage

For example

```
// outside your render() method
const renderField = (field) => (
    <FormGroup controlId='login'>
        <FormControl name='email' placeholder='Login' />
    </FormGroup>
)

// inside your render() method
<Field name="myField" component={renderField}/>
```

Comment: Okay but it seems that according to the form, the inputs are empty. Should we pass the value in an onChange?

Comment: I believe you'd have access to the value from the field argument. So to get the field value you could do something like `field.input.value`.

or `<FormControl {...field.input}>`